# Angular Observables DialogWindow SyncFusion

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add frontend (Angular) to backend application and I have very little experience in this regard, so I got stuck.

The following code prints Error. 
 The code is related to the pop-up window with two options: OK and QUIT. 
 This happens when OK is choosen. 
 The code is supposed to remove data from DB (what happens) and hide pop-up window (what does not happen).

```
private deleteNeed: EmitType<object> = () => {
  console.log(this.needToDelete);
  this.needService.delete(this.needToDelete).subscribe( r => {
    this.toastService.success('Need deleted!');
    this.ejDialog.hide();
    this.loadNeeds();
  },e => {
    this.toastService.error('Error');
    console.log(e);
    }
   );
}
```

For some reason the lines:

```
this.toastService.success('Need deleted!');
  this.ejDialog.hide();
  this.loadNeeds();
```

seem to be ignored and execution goes to the error part. 
 Method 'hide' is working properly, what I can know because if on the above said pop-up window the QUIT button is choosen all works properly and the window is hidden. 
 When button OK is clicked the data (Need) is deleted from the DB, however the pop up window stays and to delete this "QUIT" button must be clicked. 
 I have no idea why. 
 
 Does anyone have similar experience?

Details of this.needService.delete :

```
  constructor(private needService : NeedService,
          private toastService: ToastService) {
          this.dataManager = new DataManager({
          json: this.needsList, adaptor: new 
          NeedsDataAdaptor(this.needService)
         });
         }

 delete(need: Need) : Observable<Need> {
        console.log('Need deleted!');
        console.log(need);
        return this.http.patch(urlDel, need).pipe(
        map(res => res.json())
        );
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `this.needService.delete` call is working fine? If flow is going to error part then it means that call is failing.

Comment: The respective record is indeed deleted from data base - that allows me for making asumption that this line works, however I am very new to JS(TS) and there may be something I am not aware of.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add details of `this.needService.delete`?

Comment: Thank you for additional question, I have provided further details at the end of question post.